# Как избавить от белой полоски между виджетами установленными в QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlayout, spacing

Пытаюсь разобраться в контейнерах. Как я понимаю, контейнеры создают между добавленными в них виджетами некоторую рамку.

Как от нее избавиться?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(1000,500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.content = QFrame()
        
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        
        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35);")
        
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.content)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QBoxLayout::setSpacing(int spacing)
>
> Устанавливает для свойства spacing значение.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(1000,500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.content = QFrame()
        
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.vbox.setSpacing(0)                                       # +++
        
        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,135);")
        
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.content)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот теперь просто красота!